# See exact content of bash variable? (hexdump doesn't help)

Tags: bash, hex, quoting

So I have a problem below, but my question is more generic - how to see exact content of memory referenced by bash variable to understand why they don't match:

```
# [[ $c1 == $c ]] || echo nope
nope
# [[ $c1 == "bkup dt" ]] || echo nope
# [[ $c == "bkup dt" ]] || echo nope
nope
# hexdump -C <<<$c
00000000  62 6b 75 70 20 64 74 0a                           |bkup dt.|
00000008
# hexdump -C <<<$c1
00000000  62 6b 75 70 20 64 74 0a                           |bkup dt.|
00000008
# [ "$c1" = "$c" ] || echo nope
nope
# [ ! "$c1" = "$c" ] || echo nope
```

Or does it look like a bug? I can repeat the problem with:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir aaa
$ echo 2 > aaa/1
$ echo 2 > aaa/2
$ c=$(ls -A aaa)
$ [[ $c == $(echo $c) ]] || echo not equal
not equal
$ hexdump -C <<<$c
00000000  31 20 32 0a                                       |1 2.|
00000004
$ hexdump -C <<<$(echo $c)
00000000  31 20 32 0a                                       |1 2.|
00000004
$ c1="1 2"
$ [[ $c1 == $(echo $c1) ]] || echo not equal
$ [[ $c1 == $(echo $c) ]] || echo not equal
$ [[ $c1 == $c ]] || echo not equal
not equal
```

Comment: You are seeing the exact contents of the variable; you are just getting an *additional* newline (`0a`) induced by the here string. `printf '%s' "$c" | hexdump -C` would omit that if you don't want to simply ignore it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best thing to inspect the content of a variable is to use `declare -p`:

```
$ c="1 2"
$ declare -p c
declare -- c="1 2"
```

Note that your tests are wrong because you're missing out quotes in your variable expansions!

Look:

```
$ c="1  2" # with two spaces
$ declare -p c
declare -- c="1  2"
$ echo $c
1 2
$ echo "$c"
1  2
$ d=$(echo $c)
$ declare -p d
1 2
```

You must quote every single variable expansion, *unless you really want to have word splitting and pathname expansion applied to them!* (and usually, you certainly don't want that to happen).

Even with your `hexdump` strategy you need quotes:

```
$ c="1  2" # two spaces
$ hexdump <<< $c
00000000  31 20 32 0a                                       |1 2.|
00000004
$ hexdump <<< "$c"
00000000  31 20 20 32 0a                                    |1  2.|
00000005
```

What you're experiencing is exactly this:

```
$ mkdir aaa; touch aaa/{1,2}
$ c=$(ls -A aaa)
$ declare -p c
declare -- c="1
2"
$ # see? there's a new line between the files.
$ echo $c
1 2
$ echo "$c"
1
2
$ # Use quotes!
```

---

Sometimes `declare -p` will not quite show spaces properly. In this case you can use `printf` like so:

```
$ c=$'    \n'
$ declare -p c
declare -- c="    
"
$ # there are spaces, but you can't see them
$ printf '%q\n' "$c"
$'    \n'
```

---

The declare strategy is also nice as you can inspect arrays and functions too:

```
$ a=( one two "three four" )
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three four")'
$ declare -A h=( [one]=1 [two]=2 )
$ declare -p h
declare -A h='([one]="1" [two]="2" )'
$ f() { echo hello; } > somewhere > >(over the rainbow)
$ declare -pf f
f () 
{ 
    echo hello
} > somewhere 2> >(over the rainbow)
$ # You need also the -f switch to target functions
```

You also have access to the flags of the variables:

```
$ declare -litux hello=world
$ declare -p hello
declare -itx hello="0"
$ # Have fun!
```

Comment: yep this exactly answers the question, not sure how I could find the answer  by myself though :)

Comment: Note that the argument for `<<<` is *documented* as not undergoing word-splitting, but that wasn't actually true until `bash` 4.4.

Comment: With `c='a     b'`, both `hd <<< $a` and `hd <<< "$a"` produce the same output in the current bash version 4.4. So, that doesn't help any.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the exact content of the variable because you ask bash to modify it. The most basic effect is in this command:

```
$ echo hello # world
hello

$ echo "hello # world"
hello # world
```

Quoting prevents the shell from interpreting the special character # as a comment start character, and thus it gets printed.

Please [read more here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html)

The only correct way to print a variable exact content is to quote it.

```
a='a \b 
|c     d'
```

Above, var a is getting an exact string because it is single quoted.

```
$ echo "$a"
a \b 
|c     d
```

Above, the value of var `a` is exactly reproduced because of the double quotes.

As soon as you fail to quote a variable expansion `$a`, you get something else:

```
$ echo $a
a \b |c d
```

This is a very basic requirement of any shell: quoting.
And there are single quotes, double quotes and backslash quoting.

---

In your case, to reproduce what you see, the vars are not really equal, they are:

```
$ c='bkup dt
'

$ c1='bkup dt'
```

That is, c contains **an additional newline at the end** compared to c1.

Let's repeat your commands, but correctly quoting to see the real contents of each var (Please understand that inside `[[…]]` variables could be used un-quoted most of the time).

```
$ [[ $c1 == $c ]] || echo nope
nope
```

The variables are Not equal.

```
$ [[ $c1 == "bkup dt" ]] || echo nope
```

variable `c1` is exactly equal to `bkup dt` (no output).

```
$ [[ $c == "bkup dt" ]] || echo nope
nope
```

No, `c` is not exactly "bkup dt" (it has an additional new line).

```
$ hexdump -C <<<"$c"
00000000  62 6b 75 70 20 64 74 0a  0a                       |bkup dt..|
00000009
```

Note the **two** newlines at the end, now the quoted variable reproduces its internal value correctly with an added newline from the `<<<`.

Compare with `$c1`.

```
$ hexdump -C <<<"$c1"
00000000  62 6b 75 70 20 64 74 0a                           |bkup dt.|
00000009
```

Only one newline!!.

Maybe a better way will be to use:

```
$ printf '%s' "$c" | od -vAn -tx1c
 62  6b  75  70  20  64  74  0a
  b   k   u   p       d   t  \n
```

Here, the newline inside the variable is clearly shown.

The variable `$c1` doesn't show that:

```
$ printf '%s' "$c1" | od -vAn -tx1c
 62  6b  75  70  20  64  74
  b   k   u   p       d   t
```

The command declare could be used also:

```
$ declare -p c
declare -- c="bkup dt
"

$ declare -p c1
declare -- c1="bkup dt"
```

As cat, sed and some others:

```
$ echo "$c" | cat -vET
bkup dt$
$

$ echo "$c1" | cat -vET
bkup dt$

$  echo "$c" | sed -n l
bkup dt$
$

$  echo "$c1" | sed -n l
bkup dt$
```

Provided you quote the variable expansion and know how a new line looks like.

---

Your second example also has a new line issue.

```
$ cd /tmp; mkdir aaa; echo 2 > aaa/1; echo 2 > aaa/2
$ c=$(ls -A aaa)
$ echo $c | od -vAn -tx1c
  31  20  32  0a
   1       2  \n
```

In this case, `c` seem to have an space, but what it really have is:

```
$ echo "$c" | od -vAn -tx1c
  31  0a  32  0a
   1  \n   2  \n
```

A **newline**

Thus, an echo also fails (for a couple of missing quotes, both are needed):

```
$ echo $(echo $c) | odc
  31  20  32  0a
   1       2  \n

$ echo "$(echo "$c")" | odc
  31  0a  32  0a
   1  \n   2  \n
```