# Substring is not found in string

Tags: bash

I use bash version 3.2.51(1)

I work with job chains and want to start a new job when the old one is finished.
So I check which jobs are currently running and only if the job number of the last run can not be found, a new job is to be submitted.

Here is the part of my script:

```
    Job_ID=$(msub -E fvcom.pbs)

    # test whether job is still running

    CONTINUE="just started"
    # do this loop, until the CONTINUE variable is empty (i.e. job is finished)
    until [ -z "$CONTINUE" ] ; do
       # wait $WAIT seconds
       sleep $WAIT
       # query if job is still running
       RUNNING=$(./show_my_run)
      echo $RUNNING
      echo $Job_ID 

       # check whether specific job is still running
       # then job ID is present in job overview
       if [[ $RUNNING == *"$Job_ID"* ]] ; then
       CONTINUE="Job_ID found"
       echo $CONTINUE
       else 
       CONTINUE=""
       echo "Job_ID not found"
       fi

    done
```

The output is:

city.12345/1202110.batch.com kdd046 Running 4 00:59:14 Tue Jul 4
city.12345
Job_ID not found

Obviously I can see that Job_ID is present and the job is still running...
The pattern is only recognized if there are several jobs running and the pattern is somewhere in the middle:

city.54321/1202133.batch.com kdd046 Running 4 00:59:14 Tue Jul 4  city.12345/1202110.batch.com kdd046 Running 4 00:56:19 Tue Jul 4
city.12345
Job_ID found

I also tried using

...
if echo "$RUNNING" | grep -q "$Job_ID"; then
...

but with same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you strings returned from the calls only contain text characters? I'm wondering whether you have some non-ascii characters hiding in there that are confusing the comparison. Particularly after your comment below that it works if you manually set the variables.

Comment: I tried to check this out with: if [[ $RUNNING = *[![:ascii:]]* ]] ; then
           echo "Running contains Non-ASCII"
           else
           echo "Running does not contain Non-ASCII"
           fi        According to that neither RUNNING nor Job_ID have Non-ASCII characters (I hope this was the right way to check this, I'm absolutely new to bash ...)

Comment: Can you try `declare -p RUNNING` to dump out the contents of the variable rather than 'echo' it? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41409536/1168342

Comment: I don't know if you'll ever get a good answer unless you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  `declare -p Job_ID`  I found that there was a line break at the beginning of the variable Job_ID that was not shown using `echo`.

Now, I included a change to get rid of this extra line and it works:

```
  Job_ID=$(msub -E fvcom.pbs | perl -p -e 'chomp' )
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RUNNING="city.12345/test"
Job_ID="city.12345"

if [[ "$RUNNING" =~ ".*$Job_ID*" ]]; then
echo "match"
fi
```

**(edit: now, if X contains Y)**

Comment: That `*` on the end looks wrongs and this will now _only_ match the start of the string, which I don't think is right. Can you reproduce the OP's problem?

Comment: Yes, I know, I was thinking about using this with an OR statement.. Anyway, I edited the answer, it works with Bash 4.3, I hope it will work with 3.2 as well.

Comment: As long as I manually set the strings for RUNNING and Job_ID everything works fine.

Comment: The question is, why was the OP's seemingly valid approach not working?